# Error: Variable Names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I successfully retrieve all my data from my database but whenever i try it for a second time an error occured saying that the variable name @uid has already been declared..

these are my codes. I dispose my sqlcommandbuilder and close my datareader everytime i used it.. but still no luck in finding the error at my codes.. please help me.. and also whenever i save and update data on my database.. it always succeed on the first try.. but on the second try.. it gets the same error "Variable Names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure".

```
    Sub fillDataFields()
    Dim arrImage As Byte()

    con.Open()
    comm.CommandText = "Select last_name + ', ' + first_name + ' ' + middle_name as name,course, section, address, " & _
                   "birthday, picture from Users where user_id like @uid"
    comm.Connection = con
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", "" & frmUsers.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text & "%")
    dr = comm.ExecuteReader
    While (dr.Read())
        arrImage = dr.Item("picture")
        Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(arrImage)
        txtCourse.Text = (dr("course"))
        txtSection.Text = (dr("section"))
        richtxtAddress.Text = (dr("address"))
        txtBirthday.Text = (dr("birthday"))
        txtName.Text = (dr("name"))
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream)
    End While
    con.Close()
    dr.Close()
    comm.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Your command object still has the parameter attached to it, so you should make sure you create a new instance of your objects and properly dispose of them after you have finished:

```
con = New Connection("connection string here")
con.Open()
comm = New Command
comm.CommandText = "command text here"
```

Then after you have finished with it dispose of it:

```
comm.Dispose
con.Close
con.Dispose
```

Even better wrap it in a Using block as this ensures it is disposed of for you:

```
Using con As New Connection("your connection String Here"), comm as New Command
    con.Open()
    comm.CommandText = "command text here"
    ...
    ...
    con.Close
End Using 'con and comm objects are disposed here
```

Side note: I would suggest renaming your Command object something like `cmd` so that it doesn't look so similar to the Connection object.

Comment: i have a module that handles my connection string.. so i just call it whenever i need to use it

Comment: Now its working I just add an aditional statement on the end of my codes..

     comm.Parameters.clear() 

and now its working fine..